# Mailgun : Sending a message from a subdomain to main domain gets denied

Tags: domain-name-system, email, subdomain, mx-record

I've set up a subdomain in [mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/blog/the-basics-of-email-subdomains/) to send transactional emails from an application (`mq.domain_name`). This seems to work fine, as long as a **receipt's** domain is other than the ***main*** domain we own, for example `user@domain_name`.

In this case I am starting to get a `4.1.8 <bounce+ewr46-username=domain_name@mg.domain_name>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found` response. And the error code is **450**.

Currently, we have subdomain's dns records point to the mailgun and DNS's MX record for the main domain are set to point to the outlook, as this is how we are reading emails. *Also*, we haven't set a subdomain's MX dns record as we don't plan on receiving emails on the subdomain.

So is it possible to send an email from a subdomain to the main domain? If so, how could I do it?
And if I set a MX record for the subdomain will I still be able to receive emails on my main domain?

Answer (score 0):

The server handling your main domain `domain_name` is unable to resolve `mg.domain_name`. You need to verify that you configured DNS records for `mg.domain_name` correctly.

Also, the error message looks like standard `postfix` message, so you need to clarify what do you mean by  `DNS records for the main domain are set to point to outlook`.

Comment: But sending to other domains, like gmail, works fine. So I assume settings are correct.

Comment: By "DNS records for the main domain are set to point to outlook" I meant that MX record is pointing to the outlook.

Comment: Outlook doesn't produce such error messages. Either your email is forwarded to other servers or your DNS records are not pointing to outlook servers.